# No se muestra mi respuesta AJAX en mi html uso Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html5, ajax

Decidí formular esta pregunta, porque la mayoría de las respuesta que encontré los programadores utilizan **JQuery** en lugar de **Javascript**, yo estoy **Javascript** y no conseguí ningún caso igual, la verdad me parece que todo mi código está bien pero lamentablemente no logró mostrar la *responseText*, he aquí mi código:

```
<form>
        <div class="form group">
            <label for="banco">Banco</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="banco" name="banco" aria-describedby="ayuda3" required>
                <option>Banesco</option>
                <option>Provincial</option>
                <option>Venezuela</option>
                <option>Activo</option>
                <option>BOD</option>
                <option>Mercantil</option>
                <option>100% Banco</option>
            </select>
            <small id="ayuda3" class="form-text text-muted">Indique el banco desde donde realizó la recarga</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form group">
            <label for="monto">Monto de la Recarga</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="monto" name="monto" aria-describedby="ayuda5" placeholder="123456789" required>
            <small id="ayuda5" class="form-text text-muted">Indique el monto Bs.S de su recarga</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form group">
            <label for="ntransferencia">Número de Transferencia</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ntransferencia" name="ntransferencia" aria-describedby="ayuda5" placeholder="123456789" required>
            <small id="ayuda5" class="form-text text-muted">Indique el número de referencia de la transferencia</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form group">
            <label for="fechat">Fecha</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fechat" name="fechat" aria-describedby="ayuda6" placeholder="2018-12-12" required>
            <small id="ayuda6" class="form-text text-muted">Indique la fecha de la transferencia</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form group">
            <label for="telefono">Número de Contacto</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="telefono" aria-describedby="ayuda7" pattern="[0-9]{11}" required>
            <small id="ayuda7" class="form-text text-muted">Indique el número de móvil activo para comunicarnos</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form group">
            <label for="correo">Correo Electrónico</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="correo" name="correo" aria-describedby="ayuda7" placeholder="micorreo@correo.com" required>
            <small id="ayuda7" class="form-text text-muted">Indique el correo con el cual se registró en nuestro sitio.</small>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="solicitarRecarga()">Recargar</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="recargas"></div>
<script>
//INICIO FUNCIÓN RECARGAS

function solicitarRecarga() {

  var ajaxRecarga;
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){ajaxRecarga = new XMLHttpRequest();} 
  else {ajaxRecarga = new ActiveXObject("Microsfot.XMLHTTP");}

  var a = document.getElementById("monto").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("banco").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("ntransferencia").value;
  var d = document.getElementById("fechat").value;
  var e = document.getElementById("correo").value;
  var f = document.getElementById("telefono").value;
  var drecarga = "monto=" + a + "&banco=" + b + "&ntransferencia=" + c + "&fechat=" + d + "&correo=" + e + "&telefono=" + f;

  ajaxRecarga.onreadystatechange = function()  {
    if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {          
        document.getElementById("recargas").innerHTML = this.responseText;}
    }
    ajaxRecarga.open("POST", "recarga.php", true);
    ajaxRecarga.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajaxRecarga.send(drecarga); 

}
//FIN FUNCION RECARGAS
</script>
```

Y este es mi archivo **PHP**:

```
<?php
// Recogemos las variables

//Usuario que es el correo
$usuario = $_POST['correo'];
//Banco
$banco = $_POST['banco'];
//Monto de la recarga
$monto = $_POST['monto'];
//Número de la transferencia
$transferencia = $_POST['ntransferencia'];
//La fecha de cumpleaño para verificar si es mayor de edad
$fecha = $_POST['fechat'];
//Numero de teléfono de contacto
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
//Estado inicial por defecto 
$estado = 'En espera';

//////// CONEXION A LA BASE DE DATOS /////////
include 'conexion.php';
//El encabezado para darle formato al alert
include 'header.php';    

if($conexion->query("INSERT INTO recarga (ID_recarga, usuario, monto, banco, referencia, fecha, telefono, estado)VALUES(null, '$usuario', '$monto', '$banco', '$transferencia', '$fecha', '$telefono', '$estado')")) {

    echo "<div class='container mt-3 mb-3 alert alert-success' role='alert'>
  Hemos recibido su recarga satisfactoriamente, pronto será revisada por nuestros operadores, puede verificar el estado de la misma en el menú izquierdo 'Recargas'.
</div>";

} else {

    echo "No realiza la consulta";
}

//Cerramos la conexión
$conexion->close();

?>
```

El **PHP** registra en la base de datos la información que recibe del formulario de forma correcta, pero **no logró mostrar el responseText** en mi **html**, además cuando utilizo *action* al archivo y método *Post* desde mi formulario, si me muestra el *div* *Alert* de **Boostrap** que es la respuesta que quiero mostrar.

Comment: intenta colocar esto en la parte de la respuesta del servidor de tu ajax `console.log(this.responseText)` y fíjate que te sale en la consola de tu navegador (F12 -> console)

Comment: Te falto una `;` para finalizar la propiedad `onreadystatechange` debe de estar asi:  `ajaxRecarga.onreadystatechange = function()  { 
// procesar la respuesta
};` y cambia por `type="button"` en tu elemento Button.

Comment: Menudo despiste, el mío, disculpen por la pregunta, todo resuelto, muchas gracias.

Comment: button type="submit" cambia submit por button dado que usas ajax para enviar los datos...

Answer (score 0):

He revisado tu código, y encontré que el problema es que después de que la pagina recibe los datos, esta se recarga, entonces, si los estas recibiendo, pero al producirse la recarga la información del div se resetea, solo que sucede muy rápido y no se nota. Te sugiero modificar la etiqueta  para evitar que esto ocurra:

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
```

Con eso debería ser suficiente, lo probé con tu código y me funcionó. Quedo atento.

Comment: El comentario https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/48985/a-palacio me había ayudado a solucionar el problema, sin embargo, voy a tomar en cuenta tu observación. Gracias.